# Modified Preorder Tree Traversal Child Roll Up

Tags: mysql, mptt

I'm trying to roll up spend by child company including all the grandchildren companies without any recursive functions.

My data set looks similar to this format:

```
Parent A
 - Child A.1 - $1,000
 - Child A.2 - $2,000
 - - Grandchild A.2.1 - $500
 - - Grandchild A.2.2 - $750
 - Child A.3 - $3,000
 - Child A.4 - $4,000
Parent B
 - Child B.1 - $11,000
 - Child B.2 - $12,000
 - - Grandchild B.2.1 - $1,500
 - - Grandchild B.2.2 - $1,750
 - Child B.3 - $13,000
 - Child B.4 - $14,000
```

What I'd like to do is sum by child for Parent A, so the result would output like:

```
Child A.1 - $1,000
Child A.2 - $3,250
Child A.3 - $3,000
Child A.4 - $4,000
```

This is a simplified structure of my companies table:

```
id
name
parent_id
lft
rght
```

This is a simplified structure of my spend table:

```
id
company_id
amount
date
```

I know how to list out each child and their amounts for just Parent A:

```
SELECT
`Company`.`name` AS `name`,
SUM(`Spend`.`amount`) AS `amount`
FROM
`spend_table` AS `Spend`
INNER JOIN companies_table AS `Company` ON `Spend`.`company_id` = `Company`.`id` 
INNER JOIN companies_table AS `thisCompany` ON `Company`.`lft` BETWEEN `thisCompany`.`lft` AND `thisCompany`.`rght`
WHERE
`thisCompany`.`name` = 'Parent A'
GROUP BY
`Company`.`name`
```

Which would output:

```
Child A.1 - $1,000
Child A.2 - $2,000
Grandchild A.2.1 - $500
Grandchild A.2.2 - $750
Child A.3 - $3,000
Child A.4 - $4,000
```

And I know how to sum for each child (excluding grandchildren) for Parent A:

```
SELECT
`Company`.`name` AS `name`,
SUM(`Spend`.`amount`) AS `amount`
FROM
`spend_visibility2` AS `SpendVisibility`
`spend_table` AS `Spend`
INNER JOIN companies_table AS `Company` ON `Spend`.`company_id` = `Company`.`id` 
INNER JOIN companies_table AS `thisCompany` ON `Company`.`lft` BETWEEN `thisCompany`.`lft` AND `thisCompany`.`rght`
WHERE
`thisCompany`.`name` = 'Parent A'
`Company`.`parent_id` = `thisCompany`.`id`
GROUP BY
`Company`.`name`
```

Which would output:

```
Child A.1 - $1,000
Child A.2 - $2,000
Child A.3 - $3,000
Child A.4 - $4,000
```

Can someone help me? I believe I need a subselect, but am having difficulty figuring it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, select the child companies that you are interested in (table c). I've used a sub-query to easily select the direct children on 'Parent A'. Then join to the companies_table again to retrieve all of the descendants (table alias c2). And finally join to your spend_table to get the amounts which you can aggregate using group by.

```
select c.name, sum(s.amount)
from companies_table c
    join companies_table c2 ON c2.lft between c.lft and c.rght
    join spend_table s ON c2.id = s.company_id
where parent_id = (select id from companies_table where name = 'Parent A')
group by c.name
```